# input field after remove letter spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried input field remove last going cursor.. I have added for my sample code

```css
.otp_form_control {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 67px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cacaca 76%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 79px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 60px;
  width: 455px;
  min-width: 455px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#divOuter {
  width: 455px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divOuter">
  <div id="divInner">
    <input id="otp21" class="otp_form_control" name="otp1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the shake in style. We need to be fixed solution any sample for this solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: See answer, it's getting an shake